# Send email when anyone logs on

Tags: linux, security, log-files, login

My CentOS/RHEL system may have been hacked, I'm not sure. But I'm playing it safe by creating a new slice from scratch.

I've installed tripwire, but I'd also like to be emailed when anyone logs in. I don't want to wait for the daily logwatch report, I want an immediate email when anyone logs in. Preferably with their ip address too.

Suggestions?

Similar to [Send email alert on log file entry?](https://serverfault.com/questions/34141/send-email-alert-on-log-file-entry) but maybe someone has a technique for this specific issue.

Thanks,

Larry

Added: http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626+1249534744623+28353475&threadId=698232 has some ideas

Comment: Please nuke it from orbit. http://i.stack.imgur.com/cFSC5.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a solucion for log monitoring like [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net), it will look on your logs for security information (including login, sudo, etc.) and send you an e-mail when the alert is important.

It's easy to configure and you can raise the alert level for e-mails or include an `alert-by-email` on the specific alert.

It can also do configurable active-response, blocking IPs and denying access for a period of time by default.

Answer (score 4):

you could put this in your .bashrc

```
echo 'ALERT - Root Shell Access to' $(hostname) 'on:' `date` `who` \
| mail -s "Alert: Root Access from `who | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d")" -f1`" YOUREMAIL
```

Answer (score 4):

Slight change of adams solution which doesn't break if root is logged into more than one terminals:

```
login_info="$(who | head -n1 | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1)"
message="$(
printf "ALERT - Root Shell Access (%s) on:\n" "$(hostname)"
date
echo
who
)"
mail -s "Alert: Root Access from ${login_info}" admin <<< "${message}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the appropriate command to, or call a script from, /etc/profile.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware though that if your machine has been hacked it may be a trivial task for the hacker - assuming it's not a script kiddie we're talking about there - to disable the email alerting function.

Comment: Yes, that's why I want an email sent as soon as anyone logs in. -- The server doesn't get that many logins. I figure that way it will lower the odds of someone being able to prevent the email going out about their initial breakin (if via a login shell).

Answer (score 2):

This article describes how to [Send email on SSH login using PAM](http://blog.th-neumeier.de/2011/02/send-email-on-ssh-login-using-pam/).

Answer (score 2):

I published a [bash script](https://gist.github.com/ElliotNB/04211e61efe6106b01ff223e5f123257) on Github Gist that does what you're looking for. It will email the system administrator anytime a user logs in from a new IP address. I use the script scrutinize logins on our tightly controlled production systems. If a login is compromised, we'd get notified about the unusual login location and have a chance to lock them out of the system before they cause serious damage.

To install the script, just update it with your sysadmin email, and copy it into `/etc/profile.d/`.

Comment: Please try to not  copy-and-paste [your own answers](https://serverfault.com/a/915153/37681). If you feel that questions are essentially the same and the same solution applies to both the preferred method is to [mark one question as duplicate](https://serverfault.com/help/duplicates) of the other.

Comment: @HBruijn I considered that approach. However, in this case, the two questions are similar, but not duplicate -- yet the same answer still applies to both.