# Setting up Ubuntu 14 server to send log emails from router

Tags: email

I am setting up a small ubuntu 14 server sitting behind a router mostly for providing services on the local network. I want to set up sending logwatch and other log-type emails from the server to my regular email and this is the only functionality I actually need, so any other email functionality can be regarded from the safer the better side. As a note, we have an external email service provider, whose smtp server may be used if needed or more secure. I have googled several tutorials and tried to set this up, but I was unable to get any of them working and I haven't been able to decide what I actually need from them to achieve the desired result.

Could somebody walk me through on how to set this up in a secure way? If possible I'd also opt-in on short explanations on the whys:)

Comment: check this options http://serverfault.com/questions/34141/send-email-alert-on-log-file-entry

Comment: @pata_de_jaguar thanks, these are more about the logwatch options, than setting up the actual emailing